# Creating a search bar using JavaScript and an unordered list, how to hide the list until it is searched for

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I am attempting to create a search bar for a website where the user can search a list of links and the results which match the letters typed are displayed underneath the search box. So by default the list of links is hidden and then the relevant links are displayed once typing begins.

Currently I can only get the links to display at the side (rather than below, which I think is a CSS problem) and when I type into the box the relevant links are displayed but the list remains along with the bullet points which I can't seem to remove.

Currently I have the following.

```html
<div class="search">
    <button  class="dropBtn">Menu</button>
    <div class="pine">
        <input id="searchBox" onkeyup="search_links()" type="text"  name="searchBox"  placeholder="Search">
        
        <ul class="searchList" id ='searchList'>
            <li><a href="../Covid_Website/pages/buisnessGuidance.html" class="searchLinks">Buisness Guidance</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/indivdualGuidance.html" class="searchLinks">Guidance for Indivduals</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/testing.html" class="searchLinks">Testing</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/caseData.html" class="searchLinks">Case Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/initiatives.html" class="searchLinks">Current Initiatives</a></li>
            <li><a href="pages/help.html" class="searchLinks">Help and Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    margin: 10px;
}
.search button {
    margin-right: 10px;
    
}
.pine {
    display: block;
}
.pine ul {
    display: none;
}
```

Ideally, I want the list of results to display below the search box and push the rest of the page content down. Meaning that the search box stays aligned with the button but when nothing has been typed in the search box I want the list to be hidden and take up no space on the page.

```js
function search_links(){
  let input = document.getElementById('searchBox').value
  input= input.toLowerCase();
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('searchLinks');

  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
       x[i].style.display="none";
    }
    else {
      x[i].style.display="list-item";      
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close to what you want to achieve. I see the following problems in your current solution:

- If you want to keep the button and input aligned, you can have them under the same container and extract the list outside.
- The reason the bullet points remain when you perform the search is that you have the `class="searchLinks"` assigned to the `<a>` tags instead of `<li>`. so the links get hidden, but the list items remain.
- There is no need to hide the entire list from the get go using CSS, it suffices to hide the individual list items.

The example solution below addresses these issues and indicates them through comments.

***Note:*** I've also slightly simplified your JavaScript to clean it up a bit.

```js
function search_links() {
    const inputValue = document.getElementById('searchBox').value.toLowerCase();
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('searchLinks')].forEach((searchLink) => {
        const matched = inputValue && searchLink.innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(inputValue);
        searchLink.style.display = matched ? 'list-item' : 'none';
    });
}
```

```css
.search {
    display: flex;
    align-items: end;
    margin: 10px;
}
.search button {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
/* <li> elements should be hidden, not <ul> */
li {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
    <button  class="dropBtn">Menu</button>
    <input id="searchBox" onkeyup="search_links()" type="text"  name="searchBox"  placeholder="Search">
</div>
<!-- ul needs to be moved outside the flex container -->
<ul class="searchList" id ='searchList'>
    <!-- 'searchLinks' class should be at the <li> level, not <a> -->
    <li class="searchLinks"><a href="../Covid_Website/pages/buisnessGuidance.html">Buisness Guidance</a></li>
    <li class="searchLinks"><a href="pages/indivdualGuidance.html">Guidance for Indivduals</a></li>
    <li class="searchLinks"><a href="pages/testing.html">Testing</a></li>
    <li class="searchLinks"><a href="pages/caseData.html">Case Data</a></li>
    <li class="searchLinks"><a href="pages/initiatives.html">Current Initiatives</a></li>
    <li class="searchLinks"><a href="pages/help.html">Help and Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div>Rest of the page...</div>
```